# Facebook Search Graph For Page using SDK PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to search a page by the domain by using the domain name, but I am getting amy results. My code looks like this:

```
$session = new FacebookSession('fb_access_token');
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/search?q=example.com&type=page');
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$pages = $graphObject ->  asArray();
```

Should I be doing something else to search for pages by the domain?

Comment: That is simply not possible, you can only search for pages by name.

Comment: Is the true also for FQL?

Comment: FQL is deprecated, wouldn’t make much sense building new applications on it any more.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#searchtypes), you can only search by name:

```
Type            Description            'q' value
page            Search for a Page.     Name
```